# Can't set screen brightness in Gentoo system

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, gentoo, laptop-display

My system:

```
Linux gentoo 3.10.7-gentoo-r1
VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 240M] (rev a2)
```

output of `xbacklight`: `No outputs have backlight property`

output of `xrandr`:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1280 x 720, maximum 1280 x 768
default connected 1280x720+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1280x720        0.0* 
   1024x768       61.0  
   800x600        61.0  
   640x480        60.0  
   1280x768        0.0
```

output of `ls /proc/acpi`:

```
button/ event
```

When I'm in kernel 3.8.13, I can change my brightness using `xbacklight`. I compiled 3.10.7-r1 using `genkernel all`. Before the upgrade I did get a notice of "compatible issues for Nvdia users" from `emerge` but I still don't know the details.

It there anyway to let me set the brightness?

Then i found a ebuild `app-laptop/nvdiabl-0.81` and tried to `emerege nvidabl`, I got this message:

> Your kernel does not support FB_BACKLIGHT. To enable you
>     it you can enable any frame buffer with backlight control or nouveau.
>     Note that you cannot use FB_NVIDIA with nvidia's proprietary driver
>     Please check to make sure these options are set correctly.
>     Failure to do so may cause unexpected problems.
>     Once you have satisfied these options, please try merging
>     this package again.
>     ERROR: app-laptop/nvidiabl-0.81::gentoo failed (pretend phase):
>       Incorrect kernel configuration options
>
> Call stack:
>                  ebuild.sh, line  93:  Called pkg_pretend
>       nvidiabl-0.81.ebuild, line  31:  Called linux-mod_pkg_setup
>           linux-mod.eclass, line 559:  Called linux-info_pkg_setup
>          linux-info.eclass, line 911:  Called check_extra_config
>          linux-info.eclass, line 805:  Called die
>     The specific snippet of code:
>                  die "Incorrect kernel configuration options"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SOLVED]** I enter the menuconfig again and check the Device Drivers -> Graphics support -> Support for frame buffer devices, then i found this:

```
<*> nVidia Framebuffer Support
[*] Support for backlight control (NEW)
```

What can i say. Recompiling...